# Why is my offlineimap folderfilter not working?

Tags: regular-expression, offlineimap

I have a series of folders that I deleted from my SMTP server but they still exist on my local machine. I'd like to keep them from syncing to the server. The folders all follow a pretty basic naming pattern:

```
INBOX.01 Domingo
INBOX.02 Segunda
...
INBOX.07 S&AOE-bado
```

(You'll notice I'm also having trouble syncing accents, but that's a frustration I can live with for now.)

`grep "0[1-7] "` matches the folders I care about and none that I don't care about, but I can't seem to tweak my `.offlineimaprc` to skip them. Here are a few things that I've tried:

```
folderfilter = lambda folder: not re.search('0[1-7] ', folder)
folderfilter = lambda folder: folder not in ['INBOX.01 Domingo']
```

But `offlineimap --info | grep "0[1-7] "` still indicates that it is trying to sync the folders, including `INBOX.01 Domingo`.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I tell `offlineimap` to skip these directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I needed to add the folderfilter setting under [Repository Local] and [Repository Remote] for it to work.

Tho FWIW, if you erase a directory from `Maildir` and from `.offlineimap/Account-{SOMETHING}/LocalStatus-sqlite/`, `.offlineimap/Account-{SOMETHING}/Repository-Remote` and `.offlineimap/Account-{SOMETHING}/Repository-Local` *and* remove it from the server, you can actually get rid of it.

Which is what I really wanted -- getting `offlineimap` to stop re-creating it was a backup strategy when I couldn't figure out how to properly kill the folder.